# A question from Titchmarsh's The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

On pages 35-36 [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=1CyfApMt8JYC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), we have that the integral

$$\frac{1}{2i\sqrt{y}}\int_{1/2-i\infty}^{1/2+i\infty}\phi(s-1/2)\phi(1/2-s)(s-1)\Gamma(1+s/2)\pi^{-s/2}\zeta(s)y^sds$$

equals for $\phi(s)=1$ to:
$$\frac{1}{i\sqrt{y}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} (\Gamma(2+s/2)-\frac{3}{2}\Gamma(1+s/2))\left(\frac{y}{n\sqrt{\pi}}\right)^sds$$

I don't see how to derive this? I assume it has to do with the previous section, but I took a long pause from it before returning to this section, so if someone can explain this to me, that would be excellent.

Comment: @DietrichBurde which integral is that for $\zeta(s)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We move the contour to the line $\operatorname{Re}(s)=2$ then a residue at $s=1$ appears, but this residue is zero. Replacing $\phi(s)=1$

$$
\begin{align*}
I&:=\frac{1}{2i\sqrt{y}}\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty}(s-1)\Gamma(1+s/2)\pi^{-s/2}\zeta(s)y^sds\\
&=\frac{1}{2i\sqrt{y}}\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty}(s-1)\Gamma(1+s/2)\pi^{-s/2}\frac{1}{n^s}y^sds\\
&=\frac{1}{2i\sqrt{y}}\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty}(s-1)\Gamma(1+s/2)\left(\frac{y}{n\sqrt{\pi}}\right)^s ds\\
&=\frac{1}{i\sqrt{y}}\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty}\left(\frac{s}{2}\Gamma(1+s/2)-\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(1+s/2)\right)\left(\frac{y}{n\sqrt{\pi}}\right)^s ds\\
\end{align*}
$$
Finally, see that 
$$
\frac{s}{2}\Gamma(1+s/2)=\left(\frac{s}{2}+1-1\right)\Gamma(1+s/2)=(1+s/2)\Gamma(1+s/2)-\Gamma(1+s/2).
$$
Then $(s/2)\Gamma(1+s/2)=\Gamma(2+s/2)-\Gamma(1+s/2)$. Replacing this we are done.